# Searching for a pixel in an image using opencv, numpy and python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have been able to read an image, then read a specific pixel using a co-ordinate location which works fine (`pixel = img[801,600]`).

My next step is to iterate through each pixel and try to find the location (in this example [801,600]) using the pixel data.

My iteration through "img" isn't able to find the pixel.
I would appreciate any help or guidance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one.jpg')

pixel = img[801,600]

print (pixel) # pixel value i am searching for

for i in img:
    for x in i:
        if x.sort == pixel.sort:
            print ("SUCCESS")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in `enumerate` iteration function will help you. It will provide an iteration index, that in your case, will provide a pixel index:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one.jpg')

pixel = img[801,600]
print (pixel) # pixel value i am searching for

def search_for():
    for iidx, i in enumerate(img):
        for xidx, x in enumerate(i):
            if (x == pixel).all():
                print (f"SUCCESS - [{iidx} {xidx}]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Search using for loops...")
    search_for()
```

That being said, for loops are slow in python and it takes a while for the code to run on an suitably large image. Instead, using `np.array` methods are preferred as they are optimized for this type of application:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one.jpg')

pixel = img[801,600]
print (pixel) # pixel value i am searching for

def search_array():
    # create an image of just the pixel, having the same size of 
    pixel_tile = np.tile(pixel, (*img.shape[:2], 1))
    # absolute difference of the two images
    diff = np.sum(np.abs(img - pixel_tile), axis=2)
    # print indices
    print("\n".join([f"SUCCESS - {idx}" for idx in np.argwhere(diff == 0)]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Search using numpy methods...")
    search_array()
```

Comment: It looks like i have abit of research and learning to do in regards to numpy methods. I really appreciate your help.Thanks alot DBat!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue that you are having is that you need to define the `width` and `height` of your image, so you know how many pixels in the x and y direction you need to loop

```
# grab the image dimensions
h = img.shape[0]
w = img.shape[1]
point_found_at = []

# loop over the image, pixel by pixel
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        if (x == 801) and (y == 600):
            print ("SUCCESS")
            point_found_at.append((x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `if x.sort ==pixel.sort` is testing if the `sort` method on the `x` object is equal (referential equality) to the `pixel.sort` function. These will never be equal because they're on different objects. I'm not totally sure why you're using the `sort` method to test equality. You should be able to just check `if (x == pixel).all()` and get what you're looking for.