# How to check if a PNG has a certain RGB color using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, colors, png

I have a `.png` file and I want to scan through the image to check if there is a certain RGB value in it. For example, let's say I have an image and want to check if the RGB value `(255, 0, 0)` is somewhere in the image. How would I do this in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [PIL-Getpixel](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html) or [PIL-Getdata](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata)

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('whatever.png').convert("RGB")

# get pixels
pixels = [im.getpixel((i, j)) for j in range(im.height) for i in range(im.width)]

# or
pixels = [i for i in im.getdata()]

#check if tuple of pixel value exists in array-pixel

print((255, 0, 0) in pixels) #True if exists, False if it doesn't
```

Comment: Hmm... that seems like a good method, but how long would that take for a larger file?

Comment: It would probably be best to use the thumbnail method on the png before I do that, to improve run time.

Comment: This is the documentation of PIL library. To answer on your question it depends on how much RAM you have, how "big" is you png file. I don't know what you're doing with the image, but you can read it bit by bit if possible and use python generators and see your image one pixel value at a time.

Comment: I tested this on an image that was entirely red, (255, 0, 0) and it still returned false... Did you type something wrong in your code?

Comment: Does this tuple pixel value exists into array - pixels?

Comment: I updated my answer adding  method ```convert("RGB")```

Comment: And with that, your answer is marked as best :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'circle.png')
ind = np.where((img[:, :, 0]==255) & (img[:, :, 1]==0) & (img[:, :, 2]==0))
answer = list(zip(ind[0], ind[1]))
print(answer) # Prints row and column indices in tuples
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain what each of those lines do?

Comment: How could I change what color I am looking for?

Comment: Why is `torch` imported? Also, given the syntax, `answer = list(zip(*ind))` is preferred.

Comment: The first two lines are for imports. cv2 is for the OpenCV package. Refer: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de3/tutorial_py_intro.html

Comment: The 4th line reads the image. Refer: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread. The image is read as a numpy nd array, with the shape [height, width, channels]. The channels dimension represents the primary colors used in the image. The fifth line picks out indices of the numpy array that have the desired values at the 0th, 1st and 2nd positions. Change values accordingly to find the relevan pixel. The sixth lin gathers the indices into (row, column) tuples, so it is a list of tuples with the desired pixel. Then it prints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cv2` package to load an image, and `numpy` to search it as an array:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one.png')

pixel = img[801,600]

print (pixel) # pixel value i am searching for

def search_array():
    pixel_tile = np.tile(pixel, (*img.shape[:2], 1))
    diff = np.sum(np.abs(img - pixel_tile), axis=2)
    print("\n".join([f"SUCCESS - {idx}" for idx in np.argwhere(diff == 0)]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    search_array()
```

Taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961328/searching-for-a-pixel-in-an-image-using-opencv-numpy-and-python/60961612#60961612).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain what the lines do, so I can better understand what’s going on, that way I can adapt them to later problems :D

Comment: @ThatComputerGuy yeah, it subtracts all pixels in the image from the pixel that you desire to find. Then, it reports the location of all zeros it finds in the absolute difference. `np.tile` extends the pixel to all values, `np.sum` collapses the RGB values to one channel (the absolute difference means that a zero is the sum of zeros only) and `np.argwhere` gives the locations given the condition that a value is zero.

Comment: How can I change the color that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution to the one with numpy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('your_image.png')

print('Your color is in the image', (im == (255, 0, 0)).all(axis=-1).max())
```

`test == (255, 0, 0)` checks if any of the color channels equals to the corresponding entry of the tuple `(255, 0, 0)`. If all of these 3 entries evaluate to true, then the corresponding bit is set to `True`. If any bit in the resulting array of shape `test.shape[0:2]` is true, then this will be the  result.